# Classification of special symmetric Frobenius algebras over real vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, topological-quantum-field-theory, frobenius-algebras

Is there a general classification of special symmetric Frobenius algebras over real vector spaces? I know that $n\times n$ matrix algebras, the quaternions, the complex numbers, the trivial algebra, and products and direct sums of those provide examples. Are there any other (up to isomorphism) known examples?

As a bonus, I'd also be interested in the same question for the complex case. I couldn't find it spelled out explicitly anywhere just now, but I'd suppose that in this case there aren't any other examples than direct sums of $n\times n$ matrix algebras?

Comment: What is the definition of special? Do you mean this definition: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Frobenius+algebra#special_frobenius_algebras ?

Comment: @Mare yes, exactly.

Comment: All the examples I gave in the questions are semi-simple (and I would guess those are actually all semi-simple examples), so a very related question would be "Do 'special' and 'symmetric' imply semi-simplicity for real Frobenius algebras?"

Comment: Special with that definition implies that the A-A bimodule A is a projective bimodule. (The multiplication and comultiplication witness A as a direct summand of the free A-A bimodule $A \otimes A$. This then implies that A is a "separable" algebra, which implies it must be semisimple. This is true over any field.

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries Thanks! Do you know any reference where this is spelled out? Can you also confirm whether this indeed implies that the examples I gave above are all possible Frobenius algebras for that case?

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what is the other definition of 'special' you are referring to?

Comment: @AndiBauer 'special' = the defn on the ncatlab website. The composition of the comultiplication followed by the multiplication is the identity. "Separable Algebras over Commutative Rings" by F. DeMeyer is a standard reference. Over the reals the separable algebras are exactly the finite direct sums of finite rank matrix algebras over the reals, complex numbers, and quaternions. Over the complex numbers you just have finite sums of finite rank complex matrix algebras.