# Are there non-semisimple complex "non-unital special Frobenius algebras"?

Tags: linear-algebra, qa.quantum-algebra, monoidal-categories, associative-algebras, frobenius-algebras

I'm interested in "non-unital special Frobenius algebras", consisting of two linear maps (morphisms in the symmetric monoidal category of finite-dimensional complex vector spaces)
$$\mu: V\otimes V\rightarrow V,\qquad \delta: V\rightarrow V\otimes V\;,$$
which form an associative algebra and co-algebra, respectively, such that
$$\delta\circ\mu = (\mu\otimes \operatorname{id})\circ(\operatorname{id}\otimes \delta)= (\operatorname{id}\otimes\mu)\circ(\delta\otimes\operatorname{id})$$
and
$$\mu\circ\delta = \operatorname{id}\;.$$

According to a comment to this question
[Classification of special symmetric Frobenius algebras over real vector spaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/378122/115363),
ordinary special Frobenius algebras (i.e., with unit and co-unit) are always semi-simple.

How is that in the case where I don't demand the existence of a unit and co-unit? I know that there are plenty of non-semisimple associative algebras which do not allow for a unit. Is the same true for "non-unital Frobeinus algebras" versus Frobenius algebras, or can the former always be equipped with a unit and co-unit? And, if so, are there examples which fulfil the special property above?

Comment: There are non-co/unital Frobenius algebras in Hilb which do not posses a unit.  Consider for example, the image of a an infinite dimensional semi-Frobenius algebra in Pinj under the ell^2 functor.  This has no unit, as Frobenius algebras in Hilb must be finite dimensional.